# Русские буквы в URL

Tags: url, php, denwer, хостинг

Добрый вечер. У меня есть сайт, там раздел загрузки, в именах файлов которых присутствуют русские буквы. На Денвере сайт работает нормально. А на хостинге если попытаться обратиться к файлу он выдаст 404 ошибку. Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: Так что вам мешает изменять имена файлов при загрузке их на сервер?

Comment: С десяток файлов еще можно переименовать. А что если их 100 шт?

Comment: Вот тю... Вы их что, в ручную собрались переименовывать? :)

Comment: Есть варианты??

Comment: Конечно есть. Ща пример набросаю. Только скажите, у вас файлы какого типа загружаются: фото, архивы и т.д.? Или могут быть разные? 

**UPD** В общем, сделал на разнотипные файлы. Смотрим в ответе.

Comment: Вообще я хотел бы узнать можно ли использовать русские буквы. А за пример спасибо - возьму на заметку. Файлы вормата *.doc

Comment: @Deonis а какая разница какого типа? От этого зависит сложность преобразования из кирилицы в латиницу? Чисто спортивный интерес!

Comment: Лично у меня на LAMP (Linux Apache Php Mysql) всё работает =)

Напишите в тех-поддержку хостинга

Comment: У меня тоже Денвер работает)) А хостинг бесплатный - вряд ли откликнутся.

Comment: @Palmervan, разница есть. Но если вы не понимаете, то у меня просто нет ни времени, ни желания вам расшифровывать. В моем ответе есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Deonis мне не нужно расшифровывать!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В файловой системе у Вас, вероятнее всего, по какой-то причине, файлы лежат с именами, отличающимися от указанного в URI.

Обратите внимание, что в URI, строго говоря, передаются не символы (буквы), а октеты (байты). Для перевода символов, впрочем, в URI общепринято используется кодировка UTF-8. Соответственно, `http://localhost/Й` кодируется как `http://localhost/%D0%99`. Разве что некоторые древние (или специально настроенные) версии IE ведут себя не по-человечески, но это отдельная песня.

В файловой системе же все по-разному. Под Windows имена файлов — строки символов, хранящиеся в UCS-2. PHP, насколько я в курсе, под Windows работает с файлами через древнющий ANSI API, и принимает имена в CP1251 (для русской локали Windows) — но на диск все ляжет правильной строкой в Unicode. Под GNU/Linux и *BSD же имена файлов — как и в URL — просто цепочки байт. И, вероятнее всего, у хостера *nix-система.

Соответственно, если Вы скажете системе писать файл с именем "`\xE9.txt`" («Й.txt» в CP1251), под *nix файл так и будет — как указано — «`\xE9.txt`». Когда клиент приходит по ссылке и качает `/%D0%99` — система такого файла не найдет (при условии, что веб-севрер не настроен на работу с CP1251).

Другая проблема произойдет и если у хостера будет Windows, работающая в отличной от CP1251 локали для ANSI-приложений. Скажут системе, работающей в ISO-8859-1, создать файл `\xE9.txt`, она и сделает «é.txt».

Соответственно, нужно или выдавать другие адреса файлов (т.е. `/%E9` вместо `/%D0%99`) или хранить файлы под другими именами. Первое — чем-то проще, второе — правильнее.

Чтобы сказать как конкретно стоит действовать нужно видеть две части конкретно Вашего кода:

1. Как вы обрабатываете загрузку файла на сервер. Конкретно — одно единственное место — как вы определяете под каким именем файл будет храниться на диске.
2. Как вы формируете ссылки на файлы.

Comment: @drdaeman, спасибо за информацию. Файлы я загружаю через FTP. Имена там такие: файл.txt. А ссылки я даже не пробовал изменять. Они так и идут на русском: site.ru/файл.txt

Comment: FTP, скорее всего, работает в CP1251 (точнее, в системной ANSI-кодировке). В ссылках русские буквы кодируются браузерами в UTF-8 (вообще говоря, лучше так ссылки не делать). И, соответственно, веб-сервер файлы не находит.

Самое простое — настройте FTP-клиент для использования кодировки UTF-8 и перезалейте файлы. Некоторые клиенты выбирать кодировку, правда, не умеют.

Другой вариант — перепишите ссылки. Некрасиво, но работать будет. `<?php echo rawurlencode('файл.txt'); ?>` (файл сохранять в CP1251) должно помочь.

Comment: @drdaeman, спасибо за помощь. Обязательно попробую сделать так.

Answer (score 3):

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$path = "file_upload/"; // путь к хранилищу
$newname = "somename"; // новое имя файла
if($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0){
    $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name'])); // расширение
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path.$newname.'.'.$ext))
    {
        echo 'Всё гуд! Файл загружен с именем: '.$newname.'.'.$ext;
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Всё что надо, так определить, как генерировать новое имя файла. Тут надо исходить из задач. Можно просто транслитерировать имена файлов

---

**UPD:** Код оптимизируете сами, мне уже убегать надо. В общем так:

```
<?php 
$path = "/downloads/";

// Открыть заведомо существующий каталог и начать считывать его содержимое
if (is_dir($path)) {
   if ($dh = opendir($path)) {
       while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
           if(filetype($path . $file) == 'file'){
               if(!translit($file, $path)){
                   echo 'Обшибочка вышла!';
               }
           }
       }
       closedir($dh);
   }
}
function translit($file, $path){
    $arr = explode(".", $file);
    // Массив русских и английских сочетаний
    $alphas=array(
    "а" => "a",
    "б" => "b",
    "в" => "v",
    "г" => "g",
    "д" => "d",
    "е" => "e",
    "э" => "e",
    "ё" => "yo",
    "ж" => "zh",
    "з" => "z",
    "и" => "i",
    "й" => "j",
    "к" => "k",
    "л" => "l",
    "м" => "m",
    "н" => "n",
    "о" => "o",
    "п" => "p",
    "р" => "r",
    "с" => "s",
    "т" => "t",
    "у" => "u",
    "ф" => "f",
    "х" => "h",
    "ц" => "ts",
    "ч" => "ch",
    "ш" => "sh",
    "щ" => "sch",
    "ь" => "",
    "ъ" => "",
    "ы" => "y",
    "ю" => "yu",
    "я" => "ya"
    );

    // Использовать, в зависимости от кодировки , которую вы используете. Если не надо, то закоментить
    $arr[0] = iconv('cp1251','utf-8',$arr[0]);

    // Приводим название к нижнему регистру
    $lower_title = mb_convert_case($arr[0], MB_CASE_LOWER, "utf-8");

    // Заменяем русские буквы на английские
    $name_en = strtr($lower_title,$alphas); 
    // Переименовываем файл
    if(rename($path.$file, $path.$name_en.'.'.$arr[1])){
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Deonis, мы кажется друг друга не поняли. Я уже умею загружать файлы на сервер средствами PHP))) Я думал вы мне покажете как кучу файлов перевести на английский))) Они у меня уже загружены на сервер в папке /downloads.

Comment: `$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name'])); // расширение`

не совсем кошерно. лучше уж:
`pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: @shurik , я как минимум восемь способов вам приведу, как вытащить расширение файла. Суть ведь не в этом.

Answer (score 0):

[@alex_90](/users/4474/alex_90) [перечитайте сверху донизу](http://php.ua/bookphp/07.html)! И получится у вас скрипт, а главное без гадания на картах и пританцовок с бубном!

Answer (score 0):

Причина может быть и в иной кодировке на хостинге? Конфликт win-1251 & utf-8? То есть, если страница в кодировке win-1251 содержит ссылку 'файл.txt' и в Денвере все это работает, то на Linux-сервере это может не работать уже потому, что там-то скорее вся кодировка в utf-8.